# Python Error; UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2026'

Tags: python, csv, encoding, utf-8

I am trying to extract some data from a JSON file which contains tweets and write it to a csv. The file contains all kinds of characters, I'm guessing this is why i get this error message:

`UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2026'`

I guess I have to convert the output to utf-8 before writing the csv file, but I have not been able to do that. I have found similar questions here on stackoverflow, but not I've not been able to adapt the solutions to my problem (I should add that I am not really familiar with python. I'm a social scientist, not a programmer)

```
import csv
import json

fieldnames = ['id', 'text']

with open('MY_SOURCE_FILE', 'r') as f, open('MY_OUTPUT', 'a') as out:

    writer = csv.DictWriter(
                    out, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

    for line in f:
        tweet = json.loads(line)
        user = tweet['user']
        output = {
            'text': tweet['text'],
            'id': tweet['id'],
        }
        writer.writerow(output)
```

Comment: could you try `import codes with codecs.open('MY_SOURCE_FILE', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f, codecs.open('MY_OUTPUT', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as out:` the codecs module will handle the decoding and encoding for you

Comment: Actually can you show what your file looks like?

Comment: Thanks for your help. If I use codecs.open('MY_OUTPUT', 'a', encoding='utf-8') I still get the same error message.
Feel free to browse my source file. It is about 58 MB: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rku27up2ge235nh/dad90769c3dbf537f995ace595ac71ca?dl=0

Comment: If I just add `encoding='utf8'` i get an error: `TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`

Comment: If you're using the Python 2.7, the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-csv) say "Note: This version of the csv module doesn’t support Unicode input.".

Comment: yes, I am using 2.7.6 actually. Does this mean I wont be able to handle unicode with the csv module ?

Comment: The [examples](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#examples) section in the csv documentation says "The csv module doesn’t directly support reading and writing Unicode, but it is 8-bit-clean save for some problems with ASCII NUL characters. So you can write functions or classes that handle the encoding and decoding for you as long as you avoid encodings like UTF-16 that use NULs. UTF-8 is recommended." Note this is only part of your problem. The other is trying to read the JSON file line-by-line.

Comment: @martineau, the file has lines of different  json objects. All that is needed is an encode

Comment: @Padraic: How do you know the each is is a different JSON object?

Comment: @martineau, apart from my psychic powers I looked at the file the OP provided. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to encode the text to utf-8:

```
for line in f:
    tweet = json.loads(line)
    user = tweet['user']
    output = {
        'text': tweet['text'].encode("utf-8"),
        'id': tweet['id'],
    }
    writer.writerow(output)
```

The csv module does not support writing unicode in python2:

> Note This version of the csv module doesn’t support Unicode input. Also, there are currently some issues regarding ASCII NUL characters. Accordingly, all input should be UTF-8 or printable ASCII to be safe; see the examples in section Examples.

Comment: this finally worked for me! Thanks for everyone who contributed.